# ImportError: No module named 'filebrowser'

Tags: python, django, django-filebrowser

I have just installed django-filebrowser on my django site hosted on pythonanywhere and using python 3.5 and django 1.11.7. I followed the instructions in the docs to set it up. The apps are installed in settings.py, and I have used manage.py collecstatic to collect those files in the currect location (I am using whitenoise to serve static files through an Amazon CDN).

My urls.py declarations are as follows:

```
url(r'^filebrowser/', include('filebrowser.urls')),
url(r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

I also used site.urls, but was informed that 'site' is undefined.

The error I receive on the present settings is:

```
ImportError: No module named 'filebrowser.urls'
```

Edit:

I should also note that if I change the urls to 'app.urls' instead of 'filebrowser.urls' that site loads generally, but the page on which I attempt to load filebrowser (a form for submitting blog posts), presents this error:

```
NoReverseMatch: 'filebrowser' is not a registered namespace
```

Comment: How did you install the django-filebrowser module?

Comment: Did you activate the right virtual environment?

Comment: Yes, I activates the virtual environment, and I installed using pip install.

Comment: Do you have any other version of python installed on your computer?

Comment: No, I only use python 3.5 on this machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your urls look different than in the [docs](https://django-filebrowser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html):

```
from filebrowser.sites import site

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^admin/filebrowser/', include(site.urls)),
   url(r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),
   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```